# Property path does not work for getting shortest paths in Corese

Tags: sparql, shortest-path, propertypath

I am using [Corese](http://wimmics.inria.fr/corese) to find shortest path between nodes in a simple FOAF file as follows:

[image]

However, when I use the following queries, it does not give me the shortest path. As the graph has different paths with loops, the result includes only one path for each node which is not the shortest one.

Query:

```
select ?x ?y (pathLength($path) as ?p) 
where { ?x s (foaf:knows)+::$path ?y.
        graph $path {?x foaf:knows ?pd}.
        ?x foaf:nick "Ali". }
```

RESULT:

```
...
 source                       target                    shortest path length
<http://www.example.org/Ali> to <http://www.example.org/Yu>    10
...
```

As you can see, "Ali" has a direct path to "Yu", but the query gives the longer path. Am I missing something in the query?

Comment: I don't know Corese, but the query you posted is not SPARQL - or at least the `::$path` bit is not. A custom language extension of some sort?

Comment: Yes, Corese is an extension of SPARQL which is supposed to support the SNA Analysis. AFAIK, SPARQL does not support Social Network Analysis metrics (e.g., centrality, shortest path length,...).